# Iframe Resize Angular 15

Tags: angular, iframe

I need to resize the Iframe to its full content, i'm using a directive, but all the iframes are getting the size of the last one.

```
<iframe appAdjustIframeHeight frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        src="https://www.instagram.com/p/C0KyzD5J4u6/embed/" data-iframe-id="meuIframeId"></iframe>
<iframe appAdjustIframeHeight frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        src="https://www.instagram.com/p/C1Zt12OuGNt/embed/"></iframe>
```

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAdjustIframeHeight]'
})
export class AdjustIframeHeightDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
  onMessage(event: MessageEvent): void {
    console.log('EVENT', event);
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data).details;
    if (data && data.height) {
      const iframe = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLIFrameElement;
      iframe.style.height = data.height + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make it independent?

Comment: Is there anything in the event data that identifies the exact iframe? The issue is that you are adding an event handler that every instance of the directive will be listening for. You need to find something unique in the event data to identify if the current instance is the one that the event relates to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem. As I mentioned in a comment, the key is to find something unique in the event so you can tell which iframe the event is coming from.

```
  @HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
  onMessage(event: MessageEvent): void {
    if (event.source !== this.el.nativeElement.contentWindow) {
      return;
    }
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data).details;
    if (data && data.height) {
      const iframe = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLIFrameElement;
      iframe.style.height = data.height + 'px';
    }
  }
```